# Combinations from multiple sets where each result has only one element from each set

Tags: python, algorithm, set

So I have some sets:

```py
sets = [
   {a1,a2}, #a set
   {b1,b2}, #b set
   {c1,c2}, #c set
   ...
]
```

And I need to get all possible combinations of all sizes... but only one element from each set.

```py
[
   {a1}, {b1}, ...,                        # all single
   {a1, b1}, {a1, b2} ...,                 # all pairs
   ...                                     # all combinations less than n
   {a1,b1,c1 ... }, {a2,b1,c1 ... }, ...,  # size n
]
```

At the moment I am using iter_tools' powerset on the union of all the sets then filtering, but this is incredibly slow when the sets get large.

```py
large_set = union_all_sets(sets)
r = more_itertools.powerset(large_set)
r = filter_1(r)
```

I was wondering if there is a simple function for this that I don't know the name of? Or if anybody had any suggestions how I can avoid calling powerset on the large set?

Comment: No specific answer for you on the algorithm front, other than to offer two suggestions. First is to make sure you're not eagerly allocating a final set, work with iterables until the very end.  Second would be to see if you can insert the filter into the chain earlier -- since larger sets contain subsets, if you can filter out smaller sets (and it holds true that the larger sets based on those would also be filtered) then you don't need to generate those larger sets to begin with

Comment: If you wanted to introduce the filter earlier, you'd likely have to roll your own power set function, which is covered in other questions e.g. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/178264

Answer (score 1):

You can build combinations of 1, then 2... n of your sets, and for each of these combinations, generate the cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product, combinations

sets = [
   {"a1", "a2"}, #a set
   {"b1", "b2"}, #b set
   {"c1", "c2", "c3"} #c set
]

out = []

for size in range(1, len(sets)+1):
    for combination in combinations(sets, r=size):
        out.extend(set(p) for p in product(*combination))

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[{'a2'}, {'a1'}, {'b1'}, {'b2'}, {'c2'}, {'c1'}, {'c3'}, 
 {'b1', 'a2'}, {'b2', 'a2'}, {'b1', 'a1'}, {'b2', 'a1'}, {'c2', 'a2'},
 {'c1', 'a2'}, {'c3', 'a2'}, {'c2', 'a1'}, {'c1', 'a1'}, {'c3', 'a1'}, 
 {'b1', 'c2'}, {'b1', 'c1'}, {'b1', 'c3'}, {'c2', 'b2'}, {'c1', 'b2'}, 
 {'b2', 'c3'}, 
 {'b1', 'c2', 'a2'}, {'b1', 'c1', 'a2'}, {'b1', 'c3', 'a2'}, {'c2', 'b2', 'a2'}, 
 {'c1', 'b2', 'a2'}, {'b2', 'c3', 'a2'}, {'b1', 'c2', 'a1'}, {'b1', 'c1', 'a1'}, 
 {'b1', 'c3', 'a1'}, {'c2', 'b2', 'a1'}, {'c1', 'b2', 'a1'}, {'b2', 'c3', 'a1'}]
```

Comment: You're welcome! Note that you may accept (check mark on the left)  and/or upvote (once you have enough reputation) answers that you think solve your problem.